# OS X Mavericks install rvm WARNING

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal, rvm

When running this in terminal:

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
```

It seems to work fine, but in the Upgrade Notes at the end it says

```
 * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/Users/steven/.bash_profile':

      source ~/.profile
```

And I can't use RVM, getting the error

```
-bash: rvm: command not found'
```

I am pretty new to terminal and Ruby, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you install rvm its paths get added to `~/.bash_profile`. RVM will warn you about this during installation as you noticed. You could run source `~/.profile` each time you load the terminal, but that's a pain in the neck.

From the bash docs:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

What this means is that `/.bash_profile` is being run, and `/.profile` and `/.bashrc` are being ignored.

To resolve this just open `.bash_profile` and copy the rvm paths at the top and paste them at the top of your `.bashrc` file. Open a new terminal window and it should be working just fine.
 You can either delete `.bash_profile`, if it's empty, or copy and paste the contents of `~/.profile` into it if you choose to keep it.

Comment: Awesome, man. Thank you. Like I said, I'm pretty new to terminal, and I'll have to look up how to open and paste paths at the top of other files. Do you have a minute to explain how to do that?

Comment: Sure, just use your favourite text editor. Try this: `nano ~/.bash_profile` Don't forget to close and reopen terminal when you make changes.

Comment: Weird, you sould have `/.bash_profile` since rvm told you so during installation.

Comment: You want to be looking for this line:  `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$` once you find it in `/.bash_profile` copy it, then paste it in `/.profile`.

Comment: awesome. I found `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` and I copied it. Then I ran `$ nano /.profile` Is that right?

Comment: Yes, just paste it in there. Once you are done, just remove `~/.bash_profile` like so: `rm `~/.bash_profile` (if you found and copied that line from there).

Comment: 3 years later, this message still show during installation as a Warning in the upgrade notes. However, I checked `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`,  `~/.bashrc` and all these have the the rvm paths added as: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

Answer (score 1):

Do as the instruction said.

From the [RVM Troubleshooting page](http://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting).

If your .bash_profile isn't being correctly loaded on OSX, you need to do one of three things:

```
Create a file named ~/.bash_profile and add the RVM source line there
Add the RVM source line to ~/.profile
In your terminal preferences, change the shell from the default of /usr/bin/login to /bin/bash.
```

So, check if you have `/Users/steven/.bash_profile` in your system. If it is present, open the file and add that line at end of file:

`source ~/.profile`

else create the file and add it.

Comment: FYI adding 'source ~/.profile' at the end of .bash_profile made the next terminals to open without even be able to do an ls